# C pointer value - unexpected change in the LHS value

Tags: c, pointers

The output of the following program is not giving the expected result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *x;
    int *y;
    *x  = 10;
    *y = 45;

    printf("Before\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);
    *x = *y;
    printf("After\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);

    return 0;
}
```

### Build result (mingw32-g++.exe):

Before
*x = 10, *y = 45

After
*x = 10, *y = 10

[Finished in 0.7s]

Why is *y = 10 after assigning *y to *x?

Comment: It's *undefined behaviour*. You haven't initialized `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behaviour because pointers `x` and `y` were not initialized and have indeterminate values.

```
int *x;
int *y;
```

You should write something like this (if it is a C program)

```
int *x = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
int *y = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

*x = 10;
*y = 45;

//...

free( y );
free( x );
```

Or you have to use operators new and delete if it is a C++ program

```
int *x = new int();
int *y = new int();

*x = 10;
*y = 45;

//...

delete y;
delete x;
```

In C++ you can use also smart pointers. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x( new int( 10 ) );
    std::unique_ptr<int> y( new int( 45 ) );

    std::cout << "Before: *x = " << *x << ", *y = " << *y << std::endl;

    *x = *y;

    std::cout << "After:  *x = " << *x << ", *y = " << *y << std::endl;
}
```

And you will get the expected result

```
Before: *x = 10, *y = 45
After:  *x = 45, *y = 45
```

The advantage of using smart pointers is that you need not to bother about deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't initialise any memory address to the pointers.
So the **undefined behaviour** prevails. The program allocates a random block of memory to the pointers to point to.

Try this out and you will get a runtime error. Here no random memory
is provided to the pointers to point to. Hence dereferencing the
pointer leads to a runtime error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *x = NULL;
    int *y = NULL;
    *x  = 10;
    *y = 45;

    printf("Before\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);
    *x = *y;
    printf("After\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);

    return 0;
}
```

Now try this out. This should give you your expected result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x  = 10;
    *y = 45;

    printf("Before\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);
    *x = *y;
    printf("After\n");
    printf("*x = %d, *y = %d\n\n",*x, *y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the pointers, and that's undefined behavior.

This would give the expected result in your example:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int *x = &a, *y = &b;

    *x = 10;
    *y = 45;

    std::cout << *x << " " << *y << std::endl;

    *x = *y;

    std::cout << *x << " " << *y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```